# Вывод из базы в jtable

Tags: jtable, swing, java, mysql

Всем доброго дня. :) Поможете разобраться?

Допустим, у меня есть такая таблица:

```
id | names |total_q | time |part_q
----------------------------------
1  | class A | 15 | 08:00 | 12
2  | class A | 15 | 10:00 | 10
3  | class B | 25 | 08:00 | 15
4  | class B | 25 | 10:00 | 18
```

Это название классов, общее количество учеников, время уроков и количество посещаемости из общего количества учеников.

Мне нужно, чтобы в моей программе выводил эту таблицу в таком виде:

```
 name | total_q | 08:00 | 10:00 |
 --------------------------------
 class A | 15 |   12      | 10  |
 class B | 25 |   15      | 18  |
```

Только не знаю, как это делается. Я смогла лишь вывести точно так, как в базе сохранено.

```
 String query="Select name,total_q,time,part_q from lessons";
            ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(query);
            ResultSetMetaData resmetadata=rs.getMetaData();
            int columns=resmetadata.getColumnCount();
            DefaultTableModel dtm=new DefaultTableModel();
            Vector columns_name=new Vector();
            Vector data_rows=new Vector();

           columns_name.addElement("name");
           columns_name.addElement("total_q");
           columns_name.addElement("time");
           columns_name.addElement("part_q");

            dtm.setColumnIdentifiers(columns_name);

            while(rs.next()){
                data_rows=new Vector();
                for(int j=1;j<columns+1;j++){

                    data_rows.addElement(rs.getString(j));

                }
                dtm.addRow(data_rows);

            }

            jTable1.setModel(dtm);

        }
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, переделать в выше описанный вид.

Comment: Посмотрите http://easy4web.ru/?p=1099

Comment: Спасибо! Вы мне очень помогли! Даже не догадывалась, что есть такая штука как pivot!